# YATSD: distributed-systems vs distributed-computing

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Yet Another Tag Synonym Discussion: [distributed-systems](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distributed-systems) or [distributed-computing](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distributed-computing)? The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_computing) is called *distributed computing*, but *distributed systems* are the object of study. I feel like a question is about distributed systems, and belongs to the field called distributed computing — so the tag should be *distributed systems*.

Comment: +1, and I agree with everything you said, except possibly the conclusion... I have a mild preference for distributed computing, for no really great reason. I suppose keeping the computing version would at least be consistent (from the point of view of style) with the [tag:parallel-computing] tag.

Comment: YATSD is not very informative.

Answer (score 6):

I would not worry too much about this. A merger in either direction should be fine.

Conferences in the field use all possible variants: "[distributed computing](http://www.podc.org/)", "[distributed systems](http://www.opodis.net/)", "[distributed processing](http://www.ipdps.org/)", "[distributed computing systems](http://icdcs-2012.org/)", etc.

Comment: As this is the only (remaining) answer and has a number of up- but no downvotes, I took action and merged [tag:distributed-computing] into [tag:distributed-systems]. The latter seems to be a tad more general to me so it stays. It can be combined with [tag:algorithms] or [tag:computability] if needed.